# Angular 2 event not being triggered in <td>

Tags: html, angular

I have implemented some functions for swiping left and right on my web page. 
I have used Angular 2 touch events to call them, inside a `div` like this:

```
<div (touchstart)="touchStart($event);" (touchend)="touchEnd($event);" (touchmove)="touchMove($event);" (touchcancel)="touchCancel($event);">

<div class="mnd"> 
  <ul>
    <a (click)="minusMnd()"> <li class="forrige"> &#10094; </li> </a>
    <a (click)="plussMnd()"> <li class="neste">  &#10095; </li> </a>
    <li>{{maanedNavn[maaned-1]}}<br>
      <span style="font-size:18px">{{aaret}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="kalender">
    <table *ngIf="datoer">
        <tr>
          <th>Man</th>
          <th>Tir</th>
          <th>Ons</th>
          <th>Tor</th>
          <th>Fre</th>
          <th>Lør</th>
          <th>Søn</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let cell of ukeEn()">
                {{cell.text}}
                <div *ngIf="datoerContains(cell) != null">
                <div class="circle" *ngFor="let circle of datoerContains(cell)"></div>
                <div class="details" *ngFor="let circle of datoerContains(cell)"> 
                  {{circle.skole}} <br>
                  {{circle.kommentar}} <br>
                  SFO: {{circle.sfodag}}
                </div>
                </div>
            </td>            
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</div>
```

The swipe functions are working perfectly, except when I swipe on the `td`'s. And I have no idea why it's working everywhere else in this `div` - swiping the `th`'s are also working.

Any ideas of why it doesn't work on the `td`'s? Is is because of the `div`'s inside them? 
I have tried to put the events inside the `td` with no result.

Comment: Care to create a plunk?

Comment: @AmitDahan It's a huge project, so it's difficult...

Comment: So you're saying all 3 events don't trigger when originating from `<td>` tags?

Comment: @AmitDahan touchstart is being triggered, I have testet with a console.log. But the other is not working, no.